# Angular input text field does not dynamically clear with empty string

Tags: angular

I am trying **not** to use the following (in my `app.component.html`)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="username">

<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="username === ''" (click)="onResetUser()">
    Reset User
</button>
```

with the logic in `app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {

  username: string = "";

  onResetUser() {
    this.username = "";
  }
}
```

**but instead** get the following to work dynamically:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="onUpdateUsername($event)">

<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="usernameFieldEmpty" (click)="onResetUser()">
    Reset User
</button>
```

and the logic:

```
export class AppComponent {

  username: string = "";
  usernameFieldEmpty: boolean = true;

  onResetUser() {
    this.username = "";
    this.usernameFieldEmpty = true;
  }

  onUpdateUsername(event: any) {
    this.username = event.target.value;
    this.setUsernameFieldStatus();
  }

  setUsernameFieldStatus() {
    this.username === "" ? 
      this.usernameFieldEmpty = true : 
      this.usernameFieldEmpty = false;
  }
}
```

The disabling part works correctly, but in the second case, when I click the reset button, the content of the input field does not clear. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never passing the value back to your input. The following should do the trick.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="username" (input)="onUpdateUsername($event)">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wrongly thought the `[ngModel]="username"` was exclusive to the other solution, so I left it out for the dynamic implementation...

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to fix this for all your components
TLDR:
add this to your AppModule:

```js
    DefaultValueAccessor.prototype.registerOnChange = function (fn: (_: string | null) => void): void {
      this.onChange = (value: string | null) => {
        fn(value === '' ? null : value);
      };
    };
```

To summarize, this is a known issue is angular that reported here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45317
And can't be fixed unless you use this little hack because of much older issue explained here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3009
That prevent overriding the default behavior of angular globally.
Hope it helps.